# Can I deploy a MERN project without a separate frontend and backend directory?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, deployment

I created my first full-stack website, and I'm looking to deploy it. I realize now that I should have created a separate frontend and backend folder from the start, but as I was pretty much learning as I created it, I unfortunately didn't do this. I've tried to separate everything after, but I'm having such a hard time doing so. I can't even access my live server right now and I feel like at this point I've done more damage than fix it.

Right now, my files are structured like this:

```
public
--vite.svg
server
--src
----models
----routes
----.env
----index.js
--package-lock.json
--package.json
src
--assets
----**
--components
----**
--hooks
----**
--App.css
--App.jsx
--index.css
--main.jsx
.gitignore
README
index.html
package-lock.json
package.json
vite.config.js
```

I'm kind of freaking out right now cause I feel like I really screwed up. If anyone knows if this is still deployable, and if not, please help me so that I can structure it properly without messing anything up.

I tried to create a frontend folder separately, but it ended up being confusing due to the fact that I had one package.json for the root dir as well as the frontend. I couldn't get my live vite development server to even load my webpage after this.